# ESRI Flex API - Dealing With Graphics Layers in Polar Regions

Tags: arcgis-flex-api

I have developed a Flex app that incorporates a number of geo-processing functions.  The Base Layer of this app is the standard ESRI World Imagery in Web Mercator coordinate space.

One of these geo-processing functions is a glorified buffer service that can (and often) gets run in or near the polar regions.  The graphics in these locations run-off the map (see attached image)
[image]

So, I have 2 questions about dealing with this situation:

1. Is there some way to confine the graphics layer to the map surface,
   just like ArcMap does?
2. Is there an algorithm I could use (client side) to draw the graphics
   like they would fall on an actual globe?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to, as for example, google maps does, tile the world map? Do they match up?

Comment: Why not consider using a REST Geometry service to [Project](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/project.html) and [Densify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/densify.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Kirk, but I dont see how Project or Densify would solve this problem.  The gp service is already returning the results using the same spatial reference as the map (in this case Web Mercator).

Comment: 2. Can you show polar regions in Transverse Mercator? Don't they approach infinity or something so your graphic would be impossibly large? Would using an different projection system and a different base map be an option?

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with polar regions, it is best to use Projected coordinate systems that are meant for polar regions.

Most of the well known Projections are pretty much useless when you deal with polar regions, and you will face nothing but problems.